# How to save pd.read_html dataframes as html file?

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe

I have html file.
I make list with dataframes with this comand:

```
html_df = pd.read_html(folder + '/' + file)
```

I delete values from few dfs in list and now I need save it as new html file with original structure.

P. S. Dataframes must keeping as separate tables.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. If you got better decision, feel free to add it.
HTML file with result looks ugly, but it's readable with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import codecs

# read file
folder = 'folder_path'
file = 'file_name.html'
html_df = pd.read_html(folder + '/' + file)

# check dataframes
# I need keep data from some dataframes

html_match = re.compile(r'_TOM$|_TOD$')
df_check = []
for i, df in enumerate(html_df):
    for col in df.columns:
        try:
            if len(df[df[col].str.contains(html_match) == True]) != 0:
                df_check.append(i)
            else:
                continue
        except AttributeError:
            continue

# clear all tables except dataframe with '_TOM$|_TOD$'
for i in range(len(html_df)):
    if i in df_check:
        continue
    else:
        html_df[i][html_df[i].columns[1:]] = ''


# make str to put all tables togever
html_all = str()
# pattern to clear string
pat = re.compile(r"[ ]{2,}")

# put all dataframes at one string
# to make html-code I used df.to_markdown.
html_all = str()
for i in range(len(html_df)):
    ner_str = str(html_df[i].to_markdown(tablefmt="html", index=False))
    ner_str = re.sub(pat, '''<br>
    ''', ner_str)
    html_all = '<br>'.join([html_all, ner_str])

# save result
# right encoding is very important
file1 = 'new_file.html'
with codecs.open(folder + '/' + file1, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    f.write(html_all)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

assume the HTML is not complex and you can use pandas to render to a html file.

for example:

```
html_df = pd.to_html(folder + '/' + output_file)
```

formal documentation:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: Then I read html file I get list with many dfs, so this decision is irrelevant for me. But thanks!